# How to do string concatination in nested SpEL expression

Tags: spring, spring-el

I am trying to do a stringConcat for a neste SpEL expression -

I am getting hostName from a bean

```
<bean id="localhost" class="java.net.InetAddress" factory-method="getLocalHost" />
```

Now in another bean I want to append hostName in the input to my constructor based on some regex match.

```
<bean id="worker" class="a.b">
    <constructor-arg value="#{localhost.hostName matches '.*north-usa.*' ? '${taskList}-#{conf.version}-#{localhost.hostName}' : '${taskList}-#{conf.version}' "/>
</bean>
```

For some reason this is output of this is the literal string where only taskList is getting resolved -

```
taskListA-#{conf.version}-#{localhost.hostName}
```

I want to achieve

```
taskListA-someConfVersion-someHostName
```

So far I have tried

```
<bean id="worker" class="a.b">
    <constructor-arg value="#{localhost.hostName matches '.*north-usa.*' ? "${taskList}-#{conf.version}-#{localhost.hostName}" : "${taskList}-#{conf.version}" "/>
</bean>

<bean id="worker" class="a.b">
    <constructor-arg value="#{localhost.hostName matches '.*north-usa.*' ? '${taskList}-conf.version-localhost.hostName' : '${taskList}-#conf.version' "/>
</bean>

<bean id="worker" class="a.b">
    <constructor-arg value="#{localhost.hostName matches '.*north-usa.*' ? '#(${taskList}-conf.version-localhost.hostName)' : '${taskList}-conf.version' "/>
</bean>
```

But none of them worked. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware if there is something like nested expressions in SpEL, but I know how to do string concatenation:

```
#{localhost.hostName matches '.*north-usa.*' ? '${taskList}-' + conf.version + '-' + localhost.hostName : '${taskList}-' + conf.version}
```